# Permission denied for build.sh file

Tags: permissions, travis-ci

```
$ ./build.sh --quiet verify

/home/travis/build.sh: line 59: ./build.sh: Permission denied. 

The command "./build.sh --quiet verify" exited with 126.
```

[image]

Comment: can you show the permissions on the build.sh file?

Comment: What's on line 59?

Comment: don't know because /home/travis/build.sh file exist in travis-ci.org

Answer (score 178, accepted):

Looks like you need to check in the file `build.sh` with execution permissions. Please try the following from your own machine:

```
git update-index --add --chmod=+x build.sh
git commit -m 'Make build.sh executable'
git push
```

Comment: I've been using git since 2007 and this is the first time I have seen this solution. *slow clap*

Comment: What's wrong with plain old `chmod +x build.sh && git add build.sh`?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq that doesn't work on windows even when using git bash. So you have to add it to the git-history and then adjust the index to save the permission.

Comment: Before runnning `git commit`, I ran git status and it shows the same file as being tracked and untracked. I commited and was fine but next time I `git add`ed the file, the permissions were lost.

Comment: Wow. Very useful coming from a Windows world but building .NET Core on Ubuntu in Azure.

Comment: Hey @AprilPolubiec How did you fixed that, coz I am also facing the same issue?

Comment: @Rupesh I wasn't able to... instead I just followed @Lanayx's recommendation below to add the `chmod` command in travis.yml

Comment: My Git version (2.28.0) automatically updates the git index when you change a file's permission. I did a git diff on a file whose permissions I changed and I got the following deploy-scripts/bitbucket/install_phantomjs.sh w/deploy-scripts/bitbucket/install_phantomjs.sh changed file mode from 100644 to 100755 You can the git add and push!

Answer (score 67):

You can grant the needed permission by adding this lines to the **.travis.yml**

```
before_install:
  - chmod +x build.sh
```

Answer (score 19):

## Run the script using bash

**Another option would be to run the script using bash**, this would omit the need to modify the files' permissions.

```
bash path/to/file.sh
```

Alternatively:

```
sh path/to/file.sh
```

---

### *Note that*

In this case you're **not** *executing* the script itself, you're *executing* `bash` or `sh` which then *runs* the script. Therefore the script does not need to be *executable*.

Make sense?

Comment: is there a reason one would want to run bash instead of the script?  Are there benefits one way or the other?

Comment: It's just a useful way to omit having to modify file permissions. (On my mac I need sudo in order to alter file permissions. On travis-ci you can't always use sudo. I needed one way to run my tests that would work on both. And manually altering file permissions locally didn't seem like the best way...) @Josh

Answer (score 12):

simply run at the path where the build.sh file is

`chmod +x build.sh`

Comment: Thank you, this is the only thing that worked for me.