# Travis failed with status code 127

Tags: javascript, node.js, travis-ci

I am using travis for building my project. I am having a deploy script something like below,

```
deploy:
  provider: script
  script:
    - npm run deploy
    - npm run test:deploy-results
  skip-cleanup: true
  on:
    branch: build
```

Here is how the npm script in `package.json` looks like,

```
"test:deploy-results": "node ./scripts/deploy-test-reports.js",
```

Travis is failing with status code 127. I tried to find some info but couldn't get any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading more, I figured it out that it is a [Linux error code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763156/127-return-code-from) for not able to find the interpreter/compiler or missing executable.

Also, I need to add multiple deploy provider for executing multiple scripts in `.travis.yml` like below

```
deploy:
  skip_cleanup: true
  # Publish docs
  provider: script
  script: npm run test:deploy-results
  on:
    branch: build
  # Test reports
  provider: script
  script: npm run test:deploy-results
  on:
    branch: build
```

Comment: I think the syntax for that skip-cleanup is with an underscore rather than hyphen 'skip_cleanup'

Answer (score 3):

If you want to execute multiple scripts, you can also bundle them in a single shell script (like `scripts/deploy.sh`) and execute this one in your deploy step:

**.travis.yml**

```
deploy:
  provider: script
  script: bash scripts/deploy.sh
  on:
    branch: master
```

**scripts/deploy.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 'Hello'
echo 'World'
```

It is equivalent to:

**.travis.yml**

```
deploy:
  - provider: script
    script: echo 'Hello'
    on:
      branch: master
  - provider: script
    skip_cleanup: true
    script: echo 'World'
    on:
      branch: master
```

**Tip:** Make sure to use LF line endings in the shell script, otherwise you will receive this error:

> scripts/deploy.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found

Happens often with Windows systems because they use CRLF line endings.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing but didn't update my answer!

Answer (score 0):

I got this because I was using a script that was not executable by Travis. Changing the permissions before executing solved it for me.

Something like this:

```yaml
script: chmod +x scripts/deploy.sh && scripts/deploy.sh
```

Comment: I also had this issue and realised it after moving the script out of the deploy and into the script section (which threw `/home/travis/.travis/functions: line 109: script.sh: Permission denied.`). You can commit the file with the correct permissions using `git update-index --add --chmod=+x build.sh` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/42187039