# Travis run-check permission denied error solution?

Tags: java, gradle, travis-ci

I spent a few hours on searching how to resolve this error but can't find any solution to do so. My gradle build is successful, and this is the first time I am getting a permission denied for my `run-checks.sh`.

Even if I revert to old code that passes the travis checks, it gives me the same permission denied as well.

I was wondering is it affected by the idea/workspace.xml file?

Any idea how I could go about this?

```
0.00s$ ./config/travis/run-checks.sh && travis_retry ./gradlew clean 
checkstyleMain checkstyleTest headless allTests coverage coveralls asciidoctor 
copyDummySearchPage
/home/travis/.travis/job_stages: line 104: ./config/travis/run-checks.sh: 
Permission denied
```

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: I think you should clearly describe what exactly you are doing. And then: the message is about file system permissions. Did you check the permissions of that file?!

Answer (score 2):

Travis is trying to run a file `./config/travis/run-checks.sh`, but it doesn't have permissions to execute that file.

You'll need to give it permissions depending on where `run-checks.sh` lives. If this is something from your repo, you can give it permission to execute with:

`git update-index --add --chmod=+x ./config/travis/run-checks.sh
git commit -m "Added permissions for run-checks.sh"
git push`

If it's a script that's only available and found in travis' own environment, then you'll need travis to execute giving the permission.

`before_script:
  - chmod +x build.sh`

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42714604/245268